# LOCK TABLES is locking current transaction

Tags: mysql, transaction

While I do some changes to a table in `innodb` I want to lock the table. But I can't make it work. After locking the table I can't alter the table in the same transaction

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1099 Table 'account' was locked with a
> READ lock and can't be updated

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLES `account` READ;
ALTER TABLE `account` DROP FOREIGN KEY `account_ibfk_1`;
```

`mysql 5.7.36`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB.

In 5.7, any DDL statements terminate transactions.  That is, your `BEGIN` had no effect.

In 8.0, DDL statements can be in transactions.

In either case, if you do not have a transaction, `ALTER` will "lock" the "table" as much as the implementation calls for.  Before 5.6, it would lock long enough to completely copy the table over; in 8.0, it is much less invasive.  I don't know the 5.7 details.

Perhaps you wanted only

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Do read the reference manual *for 5.7* for further details.  (And later change it back to =1.)

Comment: How can I then lock the table while I do some changes on the table?

Comment: @clarkk As Rick mentioned, it will lock the table for you automatically when you execute your changes to the table, for the appropriate amount of time necessary. No need to explicitly lock the table.